# Selective role based module loading

Tags: angular

I wanted to know if there is any way to selectively load module based on roles.

e.g:-
There are three groups of users namely- admin, biller and end-user. Based on their role, they will be authorized to use certain feature. The app is split into three modules based on same user groups with one common module shared by all of them.
Based on login, is it possible to selectively load only the module required for that particular user?

Note:- routing path is same for all, like /home, /dashboard, /sales etc

Adding a point:
In the above scenario, assume, I have generated four files- admin.chunk.js, biller.chunk.js, end-user.chunk.js and common module will be eagerly loaded with app js. 
Based on the user logging in, from the backend, I am selectively sending the js suitable for that logged in user. Now paths for all the components are same, except the part that admin will have access to couple of modules more than end-user. How to manage routing in this case...?

Comment: I found a great article https://www.sparkbit.pl/angular-2-route-guards-real-life-example/

Comment: You found solution?
Can you gide, please)

Comment: Sorry @Konstantin, could not get a fully satisfactory solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this I have done a similar thing in my project. It was based on the kind of environment. You must have seen environment file and each .ts file represent one of the environment based on the environment loaded I setup my providers,

```
providers: environment.production?[MyService1]:[MyService1, MyService2],
```

in the example above I will be loading my service in module.ts based on my environment if it is not production this ternary operator will load two of my service in the provider else it will just inject one.

environment.production is a boolean variable.

Same can be applied to imports and other property of @ngmodule, that way we can configure single module with multiple behavior.

check this out,

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MYInterceptor} from '../mocks/my-interceptor';

import { MyNameServiceService } from '../services/my-name-service.service';
import { MyNameComponent } from './display-name/my-name.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DisplayNameComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: environment.production?[MyNameServiceService, DatePipe]:[DatePipe,MyNameServiceService, {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: MYInterceptor,multi: true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is there any blog or working plunks that I could refer?

Comment: check this out, I have edited my post see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#guards)?

Basically, implement CanActivate guard and use it.

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService }    from './somewhere';

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated() && this.authService.isAdmin()) {
      console.log('You are admin, go through!');
      return true;  
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then in your router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'peasants', component: PeasantComponent },
  { path: 'kings', component: PeasantComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
]
```

Edit: You wanted to *load* a module based on this. Well, the same:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'peasants', component: PeasantComponent },
  { path: 'kings', loadChildren: 'some/path/to/admin.module', canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
]
```

Comment: But is there any possibility without using the role in the URL path. e.g:- for loading PeasantComponent, you r using the path 'peasants', I want to avoid that. I don't want the user to know the role categorization. I just want it to be like '/home' instead of '/peasants/home'  or '/kings/home'...?

Comment: URL path is irrelevant. You can simply use CanActivate or CanLoad on all paths. But then your question is weird. You want the same routing, but different _components_ depending on the role?

Comment: I think yes. I want that to be implemented. Any possibilities?

Comment: Well yes, but not suitable for a comment, better make another question, or search stackoverflow first, I think it should have been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  [CanLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) auth guard can be used to load the modules for authorised user or role. Implement CanLoad interface to check the permission for user then return true if user authorised otherwise redirect to error page.

**Note that** :  Pre-loading strategies can't load feature modules protected by CanLoad guard. [The CanLoad takes precedence over the pre-load strategy.](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-blocks-preload) Pre-loading /eagerly loading module must rely on CanActivate guard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this using [CanLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) interface of Angular. I have mentioned a code sample below. You can use any of Module Lazy Loading strategies. It can be useful when you have large application and you dont't want load all modules if it not going to be used be user and also reduce download size of web app.

load-admin-module.guard.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {CanLoad, Route} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from "@core/services/auth.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class LoadAdminModuleGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  }
  canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
    let url: string = route.path;
    console.log("Admin Module Load Guard - Url:" + url);
    return this.authService.isAdmin;
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {throwError as observableThrowError, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {HttpService} from "@app/shared/services/http.service";
import {SharedActions} from "@app/shared/actions/shared.actions";

import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {AppState} from "@app/interfaces";
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import {AuthActions} from "@app/auth/actions/auth.actions";
import {map, catchError} from "rxjs/operators";
import {getAuthStatus} from "@app/auth/reducers/selectors";

// import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public userLoggedIn: boolean;
  public currentUser: any;
  public isAdmin: boolean;
  private oauthUrl = "/api/user/login";
  private usersUrl = "/api/user/profile";
  private _returnUrl = "/";

  constructor(private http: Http,
              private httpService: HttpService,
              private actions: AuthActions,
              private sharedActions: SharedActions,
              private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.getCurrentUser();
  }

  .........
  .........

}
```

Now use can use this in your **app.router.ts** file like given below:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
     {
       path: "", component: HomeNewComponent, pathMatch: "full",
       data: {animation: "home"}
     },
     {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: "./admin/admin.module#AdminModule",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard],
        canLoad: [LoadAdminModuleGuard]
      },
    ];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
      useHash: false,
      preloadingStrategy: env.production ? PreloadAllModules : null
      // preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: yes, but since the code is there available in final dist, how will it reduce the size of the web app. It will simply not load that data but it is still availabe right?

Answer (score 0):

I used gnx-persmission for Roles based module, compoent, element accessability.
Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions